# Branching ratio of two particles decaying to the same channel

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, bosons, electroweak

When looking at the numbers for the $WW$ decay's branching ratios, I have the impression that a factor $2$ is taken into account only when the $W$s decay to different channels.

For example:

$Br(WW \to qql\nu) = 2* Br(W \to qq) \cdot Br(W \to l\nu)$
$= 2 * 0.685 * 0.316 = 0.432$

but

$Br(WW \to l\nu l\nu) = Br(W \to l\nu) \cdot Br(W \to l\nu)$
$= 0.316 * 0.316 = 0.099$

where the numbers are taken from [here](http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/theses/SteveDallison.pdf) (a 20 years old reference, so the best numbers might be slightly different now)

Is this the case ? If it is, why is so ?

Comment: I don't see why there should be an additional factor of 2 for semi-leptonic decays compared to fully leptonic decays. Can you provide a reference or link where you came across this?

Comment: I have added a reference and also the numerical values in the post ;)

Comment: Intuitively it makes sense to me to add a factor 2 because there are two interchangeable $W$ bosons decaying, so I find the leptonic one "odd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an analogy, consider a toss of two coins. The outcome of each coin toss can be heads (H) or tails (T):

```
HH
HT
TH
TT
```

Since we don't care about the order of the coins (just as we don't care which $W$ actually decayed to quarks/leptons), we can write think of this as:

```
HH
2*HT
TT
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two $W$.

For the final state $qql\nu$, one $W$ decays to $qq$, the other to $l\nu$. But the decay to $qq$ could come either from the first W or the second W, thus you have the following possibilities :
First possibility

-first $W$ decays to $qq$, thus the second $W$ decays to $l\nu$.

-second $W$ decays to $l\nu$, thus the first $W$ decays to $qq$.

So you need to consider the two possibilities. Since the two possibilities have exactly the same branching ratio, it is equivalent to have twice the product of branching ratio for final state $qq$ and $l\nu$.

For the second final state $l\nu l\nu$, there is a unique solution, because one cannot distinguish first $W\rightarrow l \nu$ and second $W\rightarrow l\nu$, thus there is no factor 2.

If the $W$ could be distinguished (which is not the case), for example, if the first particle would be $W'$ and the second $W$, then there would be the factor 2.
Whenever the two $W$ are of same nature, there is no factor 2.

Comment: that was my conclusion too, but it doesn't make too much sense to me (even knowing it is the "right" one). Probably the problem is that I'm considering the decays as being independent from each other, while they're not, since they're tangled

Comment: (by the way I think in the second bullet point of your post one "second" needs to become a  "first")